# Data extracted from excel with too many zecimals

Tags: java, excel, double, cell, bigdecimal

I have some problems when I try to extract from excel from a number format column with 2 decimals precision.

It extracts with too many decimals.
For e.g. : in excel is 2248.40 and when I extract it displays 2248.399999996 .

I user this method for extract:

```
if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
    object.put(classMapping.get(index), cell.getStringCellValue());
    continue;
}
if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
    object.put(classMapping.get(index), cell.getDateCellValue());
    continue;
}
if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
    double numericCellValueAsDouble = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    BigDecimal numericCellValue = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(numericCellValueAsDouble));
    object.put(classMapping.get(index), numericCellValue);
    continue;
}
```

Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: Floating point types like `double` have inherent precision issues which is very likely what you're facing here. Try without the intermediate `String.valueOf(double)` and directly use the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor.

Comment: What is`cell`? What library?

Comment: The value in Excel is not actually 2248.40, that is just how it is *formatted*, Excel uses double precision for numbers, so the value you extracted is the actual value.